# Generic class can't match argument list

Tags: c#, unit-testing, class, generics

Trying to write my first generic class in C#:

```
public class HighScoreList<ScoreType>
    where ScoreType : System.IComparable<ScoreType>
{
    ...

    public HighScoreList(List<ScoreType> highScoreList)
    {
          ....
    }

    ...
}
```

I have run into problems writing unit tests for it. It can't for some reason match the constructor's argument list and gives me the error:

Error   7   The best overloaded method match for 'TDGLX.FileManagement.HighScoreList.HighScoreList(System.Collections.Generic.List)' has some invalid arguments   C:\Users\eric\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TDGLX\UnitTests\FileManagmentTest\HighScoreListTest.cs  183 54  UnitTests

On this and several other tests:

```
   HighScoreList<GenericScore> highScoreList =
        new HighScoreList<GenericScore>(new List<GenericScore>()
                {
                    new GenericScore("Person1",400),
                    new GenericScore("Person2",200),
                    new GenericScore("Person3",100)
                });

        HighScoreList<GenericScore> target =
            new HighScoreList<GenericScore>(highScoreList);
```

Here is the class that I'm using as a parameter to the template argument list in my tests.

```
[Serializable()]
public class GenericScore : System.IComparable<GenericScore>
{
    public GenericScore(string name,int score)
    {
        Name = name;
        Score = score;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(GenericScore other)
    {
        return this.Score.CompareTo(other.Score);
    }
}
```

I really can't figure out what's wrong with the test. Is there something have misunderstood about C# generics?

Comment: Is that the full error message you're getting? Or does the compiler say anything about it being unable to cast from type X to type Y?

Comment: Oh,there's one more:Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TDGLX.FileManagement.HighScoreList<TDGLX.FileManagement.GenericScore>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TDGLX.FileManagement.GenericScore>' C:\Users\eric\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TDGLX\UnitTests\FileManagmentTest\HighScoreListTest.cs 111 49 UnitTests

Comment: Does HighScoreList accept a List<t> in its constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    HighScoreList<GenericScore> target =
        new HighScoreList<GenericScore>(highScoreList);
```

In the code above, you're passing a `HighScoreList<GenericScore>` to the constructor of `HighScoreList<GenericScore>`, but it expects a `List<GenericScore>`

Isn't that what you want ?

```
    List<GenericScore> highScoreList = new List<GenericScore>()
            {
                new GenericScore("Person1",400),
                new GenericScore("Person2",200),
                new GenericScore("Person3",100)
            };

    HighScoreList<GenericScore> target =
        new HighScoreList<GenericScore>(highScoreList);
```

Answer (score 3):

On your second call to the `HighScoreList` ctor, you're passing in an instance of `HighScoreList<GenericScore>` as the `List<GenericStore>` ctor argument, but `HighScoreList<T>` doesn't inherit off `List<T>`, hence the error.

As a point of style, generic type names usually start with T, so it'll be `HighScoreList<TScoreType>`, or just `HighScoreList<T>`

Comment: Actually "Type" in the name of the generic type argument is redundant... a better name would be `TScore`

Comment: Didn't know the last part.Will start doing that.